# Select programmatically an element from a dropdown button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I need to select programmatically (javascript) an element from a dropdown button:

```
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Button</label>
            <div class="col-lg-9">
              <div class="btn-group m-r">
                <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-md btn-default dropdown-toggle">
                  <span class="dropdown-label" data-placeholder="Please select">Option 1</span> 
                  <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-select">
                  <li id="properties_form_1" class="active"><a href="#"><input type="radio" name="d-s-c-1">Option 1</a></li>
                  <li id="properties_form_2"><a href="#"><input type="radio" name="d-s-c-1">xxx</a></li>
                  <li id="properties_form_3"><a href="#"><input type="radio" name="d-s-c-1">xxxx</a></li>
                  <li id="properties_form_4"><a href="#"><input type="radio" name="d-s-c-1">xxx</a></li>
                  <li id="properties_form_5"><a href="#"><input type="radio" name="d-s-c-1">xxxxx-Pair</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

[UPDATE]
I have tried the following:

```
    order_form_div.find("[id^='properties_form_']").each(function(){
    console.log("id: " + $(this).attr('id'));
    $(this).removeClass('active');  
});
order_form_div.find("#" + item.productType).addClass('active');
```

And it puts the correct item active but the text in "Option 1" is not updated. So, instead of changing this text manually, I suppose that there are any elegant way to do it.

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: *"I need to select programmatically (javascript) an element from a dropdown button:"* Means what?

Comment: No Idea what you are asking/what you want here.

Answer (score 2):

Once you've switched the selected property to the option you wish to be selected, run

```
 $('.dropdown-menu').selectpicker('refresh');
```

This should update the button. (might need to run it on `btn-group`, not sure from your structure)

Answer (score 0):

a shot in the dark:

```
// deactivate all
$('.dropdown-menu li').removeClass('active');

// the id of the element to select
var selected = 'properties_form_2';

// set active class
$('#' + selected).addClass('active');
// check radio-button
$('#' + selected + '.active input').prop('checked', true);
```